# Get particular row as series from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How do we get a particular filtered row as series?

Example dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20130101, 20130101, 20130102], 'location': ['a', 'a', 'c']})
>>> df
       date location
0  20130101        a
1  20130101        a
2  20130102        c
```

I need to select the row where `location` is `c` **as a series**.

**I tried:**

```
row = df[df["location"] == "c"].head(1)  # gives a dataframe
row = df.ix[df["location"] == "c"]       # also gives a dataframe with single row
```

In either cases I can't the row as series.

Comment: The answers here do work for any general case but fail to handle important corner cases. More information can be found in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54344511/4909087)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use the [`squeeze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) function that will remove one dimension from the dataframe:

```
df[df["location"] == "c"].squeeze()
Out[5]: 
date        20130102
location           c
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

`DataFrame.squeeze` method acts the same way of the `squeeze` argument of the `read_csv` function when set to `True`: if the resulting dataframe is a 1-len dataframe, i.e. it has only one dimension (a column or a row), then the object is squeezed down to the smaller dimension object.

In your case, you get a Series object from the DataFrame. The same logic applies if you squeeze a Panel down to a DataFrame.

squeeze is explicit in your code and shows clearly your intent to "cast down" the object in hands because its dimension can be projected to a smaller one.

If the dataframe has more than one column or row, squeeze has no effect.

Comment: Thanks Boud that works like a miracle. `df[df["location"] == "c"].squeeze()` too works fine. Can you please also explain what squeeze does? "squeeze length 1 dimensions" means it converts 1 row results to series?

Comment: @Pratyush I updated the answer above. I would recommend you call squeeze as you want to get a series from a 1D dataframe, which makes is more explicit than calling iloc[0] only for cast purposes.

Comment: Don't know which one is better, but squeeze like pythonic :) +1 for explanation

Comment: iloc otoh is better when resultin dataframe has more than one row

Comment: If you hav more than one row, then your df is 2D and not 1D so you cannot squeeze it

Answer (score 25):

You can just take first row with integer indexing ([iloc()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html) function):

```
>>> df[df["location"] == "c"].iloc[0]
date        20130102
location           c
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: It is important to note that this answer does not work if you want to assign a new row here: `df[df["location"] == "c"].iloc[0] = pd.Series({'location': 'd', 'date': np.nan})` will fail. The right way to do this is to call a single slicer, once. I have added a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54344511/4909087).